# dns over tls and no-systemd distro's

Tags: networking, dns

Suppose I have a dns server which use DoT(dns over TLS) working and up.
On systemd based distro's like Debian, Oracle Linux, Rockylinux, etc... is easy to setup

vim  /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
DNS=IP.OF.YOUR.DNS OR DNSWITHTLS
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=yourdomain.domainorotherdomainwithtls
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
#Cache=yes

systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

and is done.

The question is..is possible to setup DoT for non-systemd distro based like Slackware or Devuan?
Freebsd don't use systemd, but they can setup DoT only editing one file and restart the network service

```
vim /etc/rc.conf.d/local_unbound 
local_unbound_tls="YES"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, at least for Devuan

[Elogind-resolved now support DoT.](https://gitea.devuan.org/LeePen/elogind/commit/c2d6219300e87864d179a30ca759592eb143518f?style=split)